# ¿Como consulto en una tabla a partir de una columna tipo "json" las filas que contengan solo un dato en dicha columna?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE partes(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  id_padre INTEGER,
  tipos JSON
);
```

Inserto los datos de ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO partes (id, id_padre, tipos) VALUES (1, 0, '["1","2"]'), (2, 1, '["2"]'), (3, 1, '["2","1"]'), (4, 3, '["1"]');
```

Realizo la consulta:

```
select * from partes where tipos = '["1"]' order by id_padre;
```

El valor que obtengo es el siguiente:

> Query Error: error: operator does not exist: json = unknown

Acá en fiddler para que vean el funcionamiento: [***dbfiddler***](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2cQY3b2sPXpQAHGgjGtw1Q/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambiar a `JSONB`:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE partes(
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
       id_padre INTEGER,
       tipos JSONB
   );

   INSERT INTO partes (id, id_padre, tipos) 
   VALUES (1, 0, '["1","2"]'), 
          (2, 1, '["2"]'), 
          (3, 1, '["2","1"]'), 
          (4, 3, '["1"]');

   SELECT * FROM partes WHERE tipos = '["1"]' ORDER BY id_padre;
   ```
2. La otra opción es pasándole `jsonb` a tu query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM partes WHERE tipos::jsonb = '["1"]'::jsonb ORDER BY id_padre;
   ```

Comment: interesante, pero el mas optimo seria cambiar la tabla a JSONB , se evita realizar el CAST

Comment: ¿si quiero obtener todos los que contengan 1 o todos los que contengan 2?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM partes WHERE tipos::jsonb @> '["1"]'::jsonb ORDER BY id_padre;` @PabloContreras